# Animate repeat infinite TweenMax

Tags: gsap

I have this code which animate an object of opacity 1 to 0 .

But I want to know how I can do to make this action is repeated infinitely, each 1 second ?

Any ideas ?

```
var tl = new TimelineMax();

        tl.add(timeLine_parpados.to($parpados,0.1,{opacity:1})); // parpados aparecen
        tl.add(timeLine_parpados.to($parpados,0.1,{opacity:0})); // parpados desaparecen

        tl.play();
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
var el = document.getElementById("element");
var tl = new TimelineMax();

tl.to(el, 1, {alpha:0, repeatDelay:1, repeat:-1, yoyo:true})
tl.play();
```

**[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/c21vjgm3/2/)**

1 second between the element displaying and fading out. `repeat:-1` will repeat the animation indefinitely.

`yoyo:true`, this works with the `repeat` property, and makes the animation reverse, so it's smooth when the `div` next fades in

Answer (score 0):

It also works without a timeline

```js
gsap.to(group.rotation, {
 y: 2 * Math.PI, x: 2 * Math.PI,
 repeat: -1, duration: 5 , delay: 0
})
```